# Running class file from other directory using ProcessBuilder in Java

Tags: java, processbuilder

Currently, I'm facing a problem in running a class file from other directory.

Code:

```
    List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
    list.add("java");
    list.add("-cp");
    list.add("C:\\Users\\acer-PC\\Desktop\\");
    list.add("TestUnit1");
    list.add("10");
    list.add("12");
    list.add("14");
    ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder(list);
    Process p = pb.start();
```

What should be the correct syntax to run a program in other directory?

Comment: Declare the directory in the path. Or set the `ProcessBuilder` directory.

Comment: Means I should declare in the way: `ProcessBuilder("java","-cp","TestUnit1","10","12,"14");` with `ProcessBuilder.directory("C:\\Users\\acer-PC\\Desktop\\")`?